# JavaFX8 Font Rendering Issue

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

I am in the process of porting my JavaFX2 application over to JavaFX8 and I have noticed the text are so badly rendered on JavaFX8, where in JavaFX2 they are fine. See the screenshot below.

[image]

This issue is very noticeable when the font gets smaller. 
Label 1 using 24px, Label 2 and 3 are 13px.

I have tried to use

```
System.setProperty("prism.text", "t2k");
System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "true");
```

and the results are slightly better. 
My question is am I setting something wrong or that is how the behavior of JavaFX8 is ?

UPDATED: 
After playing around with more settings

```
System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "true");
```

seems to have "fixed" the issue
[image]

Comment: I'd suggest to file a jira ticket on your findings, font support was totally rewritten to use platform liberies

Comment: Updated with the "fix"