# Anti-aliasing in JavaFX fonts (font is rendered very crisp and sharp but not smooth)

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am having a problem when I run my app the font looks very crisp and sharp but not smooth. I have tried the solution given on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254000/how-to-force-anti-aliasing-in-javafx-fonts?noredirect=1&lq=1) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101885/javafx8-font-rendering-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well however it doesn't seem to solve the problem fully as it looks more blurry rather then the normal system fonts that you see on Windows.
The solution that I got from both posts is setting system properties (before loading the FXML):

```
System.setProperty("prism.lcdtext", "false");
```

This is how it looks like before adding this line of code and after.

[image: javafx-font]

as you can see the after image some letters are quite blurry even though its smoother than the before  image.

I have also tried adding this line of code in my css but it did not have any effect at all:

```
.text{
    -fx-font-smoothing-type: gray;
}
```

Note: I am using a custom font and I add it in my css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Exo';
    src: url('Exo-Regular.ttf');
}
```

Comment: This is the reason why I still use `Swing`, `JavaFX` still have fonts rendering blurry.